# $|x+2|\ge 0.001$ at wolfram alpha

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Shouldn't it be $x\ge -1.999$ and $x\le -2.001$? Why wolfram alpha says $x>-1.999$?

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x%2B2|%3E%3D0.001](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%2B2%7C%3E%3D0.001)

Sorry by the stupid question

Comment: Why do you need $x \leq 2.0001$ ??

Comment: See "solutions" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it must be $$x\leq -\frac{2001}{1000}\lor x\geq -\frac{1999}{1000}$$
it is equivalent to $$x^2+4x+4\geq \frac{1}{10^6}$$

Comment: Yes but why it says $>$ for $1.999$ instead of $\ge$?